# Why using the toISOString() method on a Date object the hourly value is an hour earlier compared to the original date?

Tags: javascript

I am not so into JavaScript and in the past I always used the library MomentJS to handle dates.

At this time (for some reason) I can't use a third party library but only pure old JavaScript and I am finding the following difficulties.

In my code I have something like this:

```
d = new Date();
console.log("d: " + d);

dParsed = d.toISOString().replace(/[T|Z]/g, ' ').replace(/\.\d+/, '').trim(); 
console.log("dParsed: " + dParsed);
```

I am using the `dParsed` string to hold the value of the `d` date using the format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS`

The problem is that executing this simple script I obtain 2 different values of the hour between `d` and `dParsed`, in fact:

```
d: Fri Nov 10 2017 10:24:57 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)
VM336:5 dParsed: 2017-11-10 09:24:57
```

As you can see after the parsing the hour of `dParsed` is 09 and not 10. It turns out to be an hour before. It seems to me that this behaviour is caused by the `toISOString()` method.

Why is this happening? What is the problem? What am I missing? How can I fix it?

Comment: in toISOString()  the timezone is always zero UTC offset but in your browser you get the time as per your local timezone

Answer (score 3):

The [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method produces a string in [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, which is always in the [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) zero time zone.

On the other hand, when you create a `Date` object it gets created with the current timezone of the browser/OS. Which in your case seems to be `GMT+1` - so it's one hour later than `UTC`.

The two dates represent the same moment in time relative to UTC, but different hours relative to the time zones in which they're measured.

As a general rule, every internal usage of time should be relative to `UTC`, whereas things like time zones or awareness of daylight savings should be a "view" issue.

One fix would be to create `d` in the UTC timezone as well. The way to do this would be `d = new Date(Date.now())`.

Answer (score 2):

The date in dParsed is UTC timezone (the "Z" you are replacing) while the other is in your local timezone "GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)"

EDIT: You have to write your own function for getting the local formatted time string

```js
 function toLocaleISOString(date) {
    function pad(number) {
        if (number < 10) {
            return '0' + number;
        }
        return number;
    }

    return date.getFullYear() +
        '-' + pad(date.getMonth() + 1) +
        '-' + pad(date.getDate()) +
        'T' + pad(date.getHours()) +
        ':' + pad(date.getMinutes()) +
        ':' + pad(date.getSeconds()) ;

}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = toLocaleISOString(new Date())
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: And how can I obtain the same result of toISOString() but with the "GMT+0100"?

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see below

`d: Fri Nov 10 2017 10:24:57 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale) VM336:5 
dParsed: 2017-11-10 09:24:57`

your original date contains the timezone `GMT+0100` which means it is 1 hour ahead of the GMT but in `toISOString()` the timezone is always zero(0) hence it does not takes that extra 1 hour you had in your original time.

please see the definition of `toISOString()` from MDN

`The toISOString() method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 or 27 characters long (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ or ±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ, respectively). The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: Ok and what can I do to obtain the desired hour? I need that it is the same of the d Date object